# Using diff on only selected files in a directory/sub directory

Tags: diff, patch

I'm trying to create a patch for a project of mine. 
 Essentially I have a directory with many files and subdirectories and my patch should only apply to a subset of files in various subdirectories.
I can't use diff on the entire original vs modified directory because there are other files that will be affected by diff. Is there an automated way of using the diff command to create a patch only for a subset of files?

The obvious way is to simply diff all individual files and then aggregate them in a single file with copy/paste, but is there an automated way of doing this? If not what is the preferred way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, in such a scenario, most of the paths for the files of interest in your patch file are the same except for the top most component. For example:

```
diff -u original/some/path/foo.c mine/some/path/foo.c
```

You should create a complete list of files that you want to create the patch for, but lose the top most path component. With that list, you can simply feed it to a loop that feeds each file name to a `diff` command with the top portions of the files added in.

```
$ cat changed_files
some/path/foo.c
some/other/path/bar.c
$ while read f ; do diff -u original/$f mine/$f ; done < changed_files > patch_file
```

Answer (score 0):

One nice tool is `rsync`, which allows you to "sync" files from one directory to another.  By using the `--dry-run` option, you can see which files are different.  This is a good option if you don't care what the differences are.